# Проверка в цикле с учетом предыдущих итераций

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы здесь не было повторов на каждом шаге:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
     $s = rand(0,10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант по вашему вопросу:

```
$existed_values = array();
$s = rand(0,10); 
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){ 
  while(isset($existed_values[$s])){//Внимание! Если количество величин меньше, чем число итераций, тут прога уходит в бесконечный цикл! Избежать этого можно, использовав числовые константы вместо чисел.
    $s = rand(0,10); 
  }
  $existed_values[$s] = true;
}
```

Имхо, то же, что вы хотите, но более правильно:

```
$sArr = range ( 0 , 10 );
shuffle($sArr);
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){ 
  $s = $sArr[$i];
}
```